# determining whether a linear operator is bounded or not

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let $K = \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{C}) $ the set of polynomials with complex coefficients.

we equip this set with the following inner product :

$\forall \mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q} \in K \; \langle\,\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}\rangle= \int_{0}^{1} \mathcal{P}(x)\overline{\mathcal{Q}(x)} dx$

let $H = \{ \mathcal{P} \in K, \mathcal{P}(0)=\mathcal{P}(1)=0\}$

and

$ T  : \;H \to K$

$\;\;\;\;\; \mathcal{P} \to T(\mathcal{P}) = i\mathcal{P}'$

now I'm asked to tell whether that linear operator is bounded or not.

my nose tells me that it is.

so here what I've done so far :

since $\forall \mathcal{P} \in H\;  \int_{0}^{1} \mathcal{|P(x)| }^2 dx < \infty , \; \int_{0}^{1} \mathcal{|P'(x)| }^2 dx < \infty $

this means $\mathcal{P} \in H \implies \mathcal{P} \in L^2([0,1]) \; \text{&} \;  \mathcal{P} \in L^2([0,1]) \implies \mathcal{P'} \in L^2([0,1]) $

then $H \subset H^1([0,1]) = \{v \in L^2([0,1]) ; \; v' \in L^2([0,1]) \}$

consider the following two sets:  $H_i = \{ \mathcal{P} \in K, {P}(i)=0\} \; i=0,1 $

$H = \bigcap_{i \in\{0,1\}} H_i $

$H_1 = ker \phi$  where $\phi : K \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi(\mathcal{P}) = \mathcal{P}(1) = \int_0^1(x\mathcal{P}(x))'dx = \int_0^1 x\mathcal{P'}(x)dx + \int_0^1 \mathcal{P}(x)dx $

this means  that by the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality : $| \phi(P)| \leq \|\mathcal{P}\|_{L^2} + \|x\|_{L^2}\|\mathcal{P'}\|_{L^2} \leq \|\mathcal{P}\|_{H^1}$

$\implies$ the linear functional $\phi$ is continuous therefore $H_1$ is closed subspace of $H^1([0,1])$

I was also able to show that  $\forall \mathcal{P, Q} \in H \; \; \langle\,T(\mathcal{P}),\mathcal{Q}\rangle=\langle\,\mathcal{P},T(\mathcal{Q})\rangle $

so it only remains to show that $H_0$ is closed subspace to conclude that $T$ is bounded which seems extremely difficult.

the thing is I'm not even sure whether it's bounded or not so I don't know if I should waste more time trying to show that $H_0$ is closed.

any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. thanks !

Comment: Try $P_n(x)=x(x-1)x^n$. Then $A_n=\int_{0}^{1}P_n^2=\frac{1}{4 n^3 + 24 n^2 + 47 n + 30}$ while $B_n=\int_{0}^{1}(P_n')^2=\frac{n+1}{2n(n+1)+3}$. Compute the limit of $B_n/A_n$.

Comment: @orole I've found another denominator for $B_n$ -> ($4n(n+2) + 3$) but it gives same conclusion

Comment: It is possible. I put wolframalpha to do it, but maybe I input it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not bounded. Consider $p_n(x)=(x-1)x^n$. Then 
$$
\|p_n\|^2=\langle p_n,p_n\rangle=\int_0^1 (x-1)^2x^{2n}\,dx=\frac1{4 n^3 + 12 n^2 + 11 n + 3}. 
$$

Meanwhile, 
$$
Tp_n=(n+1)x^n-nx^{n-1},
$$
and so 
$$
\|Tp_n\|^2=\int_0^1(Tp_n(x))^2\,dx=\frac{n}{4n^2+1}. 
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{\|Tp_n\|}{\|p_n\|}=\frac{n(4 n^3 + 12 n^2 + 11 n + 3)}{4n^2+1}=o(n^2)
$$
is not bounded.